# Observable<Array> remove element in Angular 2

Tags: arrays, typescript, angular, observable

I want to remove element from `Observable<Array<any>>` in Angular 2
For example:

```
items: Observable<Array<string>>
```

How remove element from "item" var?

```
this.items.remove
```

code:

```
get(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('/get_items')
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
```

and

```
this.items = this.get()
            .do(res => {
              console.log(res);
            }).map(res => res.data.list.products);
```

How remove element from this.items array?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about how to ask good questions. Please add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, where you failed, what error you got, ...

Comment: You don't want to remove from `Observable`. The `Observable` emits an array and you want to remove from that array. See linked question+answer.